# Не срабатывает CoerceValue

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Есть DependencyProperty:

```
public double LineThickness
{
    get
    {
        return (double)GetValue(LineThicknessProperty);
    }
    set { SetValue(LineThicknessProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LineThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty LineThicknessProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LineThickness", typeof(double), typeof(SchemaArrow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.NaN) { CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceLineThickness) });

private static object CoerceLineThickness(DependencyObject d, object val)
{
    SchemaArrow element = (SchemaArrow)d;
    var value = (double)val;
    if (double.IsNaN(value))
        return element.Width / 20;
    return value;
}
```

Смысл в том, что если передано значение по умолчанию (`double.NaN`), то значение должно подстраиваться под значение другого свойства. Но «в бою» функция `CoerceLineThickness` не отрабатывает. То есть, точка останова там не срабатывает и значение свойства равно `double.NaN`.

Comment: Комментарий с MSDN. "Default values of properties are not coerced." И что мне теперь делать? :(  Как мне отловить геттер для свойства зависимостей? Геттер публичного свойства не срабатывает, когда значение я получаю через биндинг в xaml

Comment: Попробуйте сделать default value не NaN. Если в dp уже NaN, и вы присваиваете снова NaN, то ничего не происходит, и coerce value callback, разумеется, не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете колбэк coerce не по назначению. Эта функция должна проверять значение, переданное извне, и подправлять его в случае необходимости. А вы пытаетесь выстроить какие-то динамические зависимости.

Вариант решения: выкинуть колбэк; в конструкторе биндить свойство на то значение, от которого оно должно зависеть, с конвертором. Если значение свойства не задано извне, то будет работать биндинг. Если значение задано, то оно перекроет биндинг.

Comment: А если значение задано, потом обнулено (например Width = 100 затем Width = double.NaN), то биндинга уже не будет. Уже столкнулся с этим.

Comment: @iRumba Можно добавить очистку текущего значения и возвращение биндинга как отдельный метод. Ну или добавьте ещё одно вычислимое поле на манер Width и ActualWidth.